# FileSystem and mountPoint in df -h

Tags: amazon-web-services, filesystems, amazon-ebs

I have an AWS instance, and I issued the following command `df -h` , the below is the output:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.7G  484K  3.7G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda9       22G  5.4G   16G  26% /
/dev/xvda3      985M  589M  345M  64% /usr
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /tmp
tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /media
/dev/xvda1      128M   37M   92M  29% /boot
/dev/xvda6      108M   64K   99M   1% /usr/share/oem
/dev/xvdh       493G   86G  382G  19% /mnt/ebs0
/dev/xvdi       493G   73M  467G   1% /mnt/data
/dev/xvdj       296G  2.2G  278G   1% /mnt/state
```

I am not clear on `FileSystem` and `Mounted on`. Does `Mounted on` mean the local directory where the external disk/volume is attached to?

Also, what does `FileSystem` mean? I have heard about `NTFS`, `NFS` etc. Is it the same in this context? For example, what does `/dev/xvdj` mean? Is it an external disk/volume attached and what's its filesystem? I tried to find info on online, didn't get satisfactory detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are concepts for Linux/Unix in general, not exactly related to AWS.

I will try to represent it in the best way I can.
Machine has disks (also called device), a disk has partitions, a partition is formatted using a specific filesystem type.

Each device has a "name", represented as a path, when we create a partition inside this disk it also create a path device with specific name.

On example below you can see I have one physical device called `xvda`.
It has one partition, which is also a device called `xvda1`.
On `TYPE` column you can see which one is a `disk` or a `partition`.

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
```

You can find those devices inside `/dev`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/xvda*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 0 May  8 15:32 /dev/xvda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 1 May  8 15:32 /dev/xvda1
```

From example below you can also determine what is the filesystem type used to format a device.
In this case it is a `xfs` filesystem.

```
$ lsblk -f
NAME    FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
xvda
└─xvda1 xfs    /     7b355c6b-f82b-4810-94b9-4f3af651f629 /
```

`MOUNTPOINT` or `Mounted on` from `df` is the place inside your host filesystem hierarchy where these device is mounted, which means, where you can see the files from this device.